# Posting string to rest service

Tags: c#

I have a string which i would like to post to a rest service.

How can this be done in C#? Been googling some but haven't found a solution which works.

Tried this one:

```
byte[] paramBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    "https://secure.mm.staging.boostcom.net/connect/rest/groups/1981891989/tokens");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = paramBytes.Length;
req.ContentType = "text/xml";
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
    delegate(
        object s, 
        X509Certificate certificate, 
        X509Chain chain, 
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
        { 
            return true; 
        };

using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    reqStream.Write(paramBytes, 0, paramBytes.Length);
}

using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()) //HERE!
{
    if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        string message = String.Format(
            "POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", 
             resp.StatusCode);
        throw new ApplicationException(message);
    }

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    string response = sr.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(response + System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

SOLUTION: I might have had the wrong contentType. Seems to work now atleast!

Comment: What are you seeing a problem?  Are you getting an error?  Is your post failing?

Comment: What are the problems you are getting? What is failing?

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: does it help to close `reqStream` before calling GetResponse?

Comment: Which by the api doc means: 400 Bad request There was a syntactic error with the submitted request. An error message might be returned and the response content-type will be text/plain

Comment: @sindrem just FYI: both `resp.GetResponseStream()` and `new StreamReader()` both return objects which implement `IDisposable`. Wrap them in `using`s appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type should be text/plain